Kendo Grid keyboard navigation - Angular Kendo Grid
I have a grid with header column having a menu option which has sortable and filter in it, and the rows in the grid have both delete (X) icon and a plus (+) icon which can be accessable using navigable=true. the rows have ID and basic data for complete information we need to use the plus(+) icon.
Here the issue is, if i use navigable the tab key would not access the menu option in the column header it would directly access the cell not menu inside. but if i remove navigable i can not access the plus(+) icon which is important to check complete details of the particular ID in the row.
So here what i need is for the navigable to be applicable only for the rows of the grid and not the column header.
I tried to check for a solution but couldn't find any, and did a mistake asking chatgpt. it asked me to update my kendo version to 16.7.0 and use [navigable]=" 'grid' " in the place of navigable true. I couldn't find any documentation but i trusted chatgpt to update it. and now it still did not work.
If anyone is willing to help me i would be greatful, THanks in advance.
